# Is running puppet possible on any particular port?

Tags: port, puppet

Is it possible to configure puppet to run on any particular port? 
Say if I need an agent to run under port 40000 - is it possible?

Comment: When you say puppet, do you mean the puppet agent/server? Other services, such as puppetdb, claim you can run them on any port, but you will experience undesired behavior if you attempt it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's the master that listens on a port (by default, 8140), whereas the agents open the connections back to the master.

If you wanted to change the master's port, run this on the master:

```
# puppet config set masterport 40000
```

This command will edit your `puppet.conf` file, which lives in [$confdir](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/dirs_confdir.html).

Comment: Note that I've made an assumption that you're using a recent version of Puppet.